# How to undo a path command in cmd

Tags: python, django, cmd

I am learning django and was trying to run a webapp but I mistakenly pasted "path('admin/', admin.sites.urls)" (without double quotes) and it ran automatically. Now none of the python commands are working, and I can't come out of my virtual environment. How can I revert this?
[Here is the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiSa2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Close the terminal window and start from scratch.